# How can I know an object is not visible when any of parent object is not visible in an HTML page using java script?

Tags: object, parent-child, visible

Let say I have an text box in an HTML page as follows.

```
<DIV style = "display:none;">
   <DIV style = "display:inline;">
      <INPUT type = "text" style = "display:inline;">
   </DIV>
</DIV>
```

In this case, the text box will not be visible to the user. How can I identify that text is not currently visible to the user.

Dont say that, I should travel up to the parent objects to find out if they are set to not visible. I have bunch of fields to be validated like this and this would reduce the application performance.

Is there any other way to find out as this object is not visible to the user?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need it to be pure JavaScript I would suggest using jQuery. Using the :visible or :hidden selector will accomplish what you want:

```
if ( $('yourElement').is(":hidden") ) {
    // The element is not visible
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

If you need pure JavaScript and you don't want to travel up through every ancestor element, you could try checking the element's offsetWidth and offsetHeight. If the element is hidden because of an ancestor element, they *should* both be 0. Note: I've always used jQuery for this, so I don't know how reliable this is.

```
var yourElement = document.getElementById('yourElementsId');

if ( yourElement.offsetWidth == 0 && yourElement.offsetHeight == 0) {
    // The element is not visible
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.offsetWidth

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.offsetHeight